# Functions call from within struct children

Tags: c++, function, struct

I defined a struct for "modules" of a program. I want to search modules by their names and then run a custom function, depending on the name of the module.
I tried to achieve this with a struct:

```
struct module{
string name;
int number;
string task;
void run(void){
    ?
    }
} Modules[2];
```

So now I want to assign name and number to Modules[1] and define a function that is called by Modules[1].
For example:
If the input equals the name of Module[0], function_1() shall be called, if it equals the name of Module[1], function_2() shall be called.

I want to call a different function for each child of a struct.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's not a child of struct. I think you meant objects of type module. How different are the two functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Function Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) sounds like what you're looking for.

You would add a variable to your struct that stores the address of a function. You can then access each item in your array of structs and call its custom function.

Try this for example:

```
void foo1()
{
  printf("foo1");
}

void foo2()
{
  printf("foo2");
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  struct module{
    string name;
    int number;
    string task;
    void (*pFoo)();
  } Modules[2];

  Modules[0].pFoo = foo1;
  Modules[1].pFoo = foo2;

  Modules[0].pFoo(); // calls foo1();
  Modules[1].pFoo(); // calls foo2();

  return 0;
}
```

You'll see that you can assign each `Modules[x]` a pointer to a different function, then you can call them when you find the `Modules[x]` you want by name.